# TypeError: get_params() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I was trying to use `scikit-learn` package with python-3.4 to do a grid search,

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
from sklearn.linear_model.logistic import LogisticRegression
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
from sklearn.grid_search import GridSearchCV
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.cross_validation import train_test_split
from sklearn.metrics import precision_score, recall_score, accuracy_score
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelBinarizer
import numpy as np

pipeline = Pipeline([
    ('vect', TfidfVectorizer(stop_words='english')),
    ('clf', LogisticRegression)
])

parameters = {
    'vect__max_df': (0.25, 0.5, 0.75),
    'vect__stop_words': ('english', None),
    'vect__max_features': (2500, 5000, 10000, None),
    'vect__ngram_range': ((1, 1), (1, 2)),
    'vect__use_idf': (True, False),
    'vect__norm': ('l1', 'l2'),
    'clf__penalty': ('l1', 'l2'),
    'clf__C': (0.01, 0.1, 1, 10)
}

if __name__ == '__main__':
    grid_search = GridSearchCV(pipeline, parameters, n_jobs=-1, verbose=1, scoring='accuracy', cv = 3)
    df = pd.read_csv('SMS Spam Collection/SMSSpamCollection', delimiter='\t', header=None)
    lb = LabelBinarizer()
    X, y = df[1], np.array([number[0] for number in lb.fit_transform(df[0])])
    X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y)
    grid_search.fit(X_train, y_train)
    print('Best score: ', grid_search.best_score_)
    print('Best parameter set:')
    best_parameters = grid_search.best_estimator_.get_params()
    for param_name in sorted(best_parameters):
        print(param_name, best_parameters[param_name])
```

However, it does not run successfully, the error message looks like this:

```
Fitting 3 folds for each of 1536 candidates, totalling 4608 fits
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/xiangru/PycharmProjects/machine_learning_note_with_sklearn/grid search.py", line 36, in <module>
    grid_search.fit(X_train, y_train)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/sklearn/grid_search.py", line 732, in fit
    return self._fit(X, y, ParameterGrid(self.param_grid))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/sklearn/grid_search.py", line 493, in _fit
    base_estimator = clone(self.estimator)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/sklearn/base.py", line 47, in clone
    new_object_params[name] = clone(param, safe=False)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/sklearn/base.py", line 35, in clone
    return estimator_type([clone(e, safe=safe) for e in estimator])
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/sklearn/base.py", line 35, in <listcomp>
    return estimator_type([clone(e, safe=safe) for e in estimator])
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/sklearn/base.py", line 35, in clone
    return estimator_type([clone(e, safe=safe) for e in estimator])
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/sklearn/base.py", line 35, in <listcomp>
    return estimator_type([clone(e, safe=safe) for e in estimator])
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/sklearn/base.py", line 45, in clone
    new_object_params = estimator.get_params(deep=False)
TypeError: get_params() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'
```

I also tried to use only

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    pipeline.get_params()
```

It gives the same error message.
Who knows how to fix this?

Comment: This error is almost always misleading, and _actually_ means that you're calling an instance method on the class, rather than the instance (like calling `dict.keys()` instead of `d.keys()` on a `dict` named `d`). Is `best_estimator_` giving you _an estimator type_ rather than _an instance of an estimator type_? If so, that's the problem; you have to construct an estimate by calling that type (with the appropriate parameters).

Answer (score 55, accepted):

This error is almost always misleading, and *actually* means that you're calling an instance method on the class, rather than the instance (like calling `dict.keys()` instead of `d.keys()` on a `dict` named `d`).<sup>*</sup>

And that's exactly what's going on here. [The docs](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.grid_search.GridSearchCV.html) imply that the `best_estimator_` attribute, like the `estimator` parameter to the initializer, is not an estimator *instance*, it's an estimator *type*, and "A object of that type is instantiated for each grid point."

So, if you want to call methods, you have to construct an object of that type, for some particular grid point.

However, from a quick glance at the docs, if you're trying to get the params that were used for the particular instance of the best estimator that returned the best score, isn't that just going to be `best_params_`? (I apologize that this part is a bit of a guess…)

---

For the `Pipeline` call, you definitely have an instance there. And the only [documentation](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.pipeline.Pipeline.html) for that method is a param spec which shows that it takes one optional argument, `deep`. But under the covers, it's probably forwarding the `get_params()` call to one of its attributes. And with `('clf', LogisticRegression)`, it looks like you're constructing it with the *class* `LogisticRegression`, rather than an instance of that class, so if that's what it ends up forwarding to, that would explain the problem.

---

<sub>* The reason the error says "missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'" instead of "must be called on an instance" or something is that in Python, `d.keys()` is effectively turned into `dict.keys(d)`, and it's perfectly legal (and sometimes useful) to call it that way explicitly, so Python can't really tell you that `dict.keys()` is illegal, just that it's missing the `self` argument.</sub>

Comment: The error occurs on the line `grid_search.fit(X_train, y_train)`. It does not perform the fit.

Comment: @abarnert on a similar context could you please have a look at this question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63533647/gridsearchcv-with-scoring-function-and-refit-parameter

Answer (score 29):

I finally get the problem solved. The reason is exactly as what abarnert said.

Firstly I tried:

```
pipeline = LogisticRegression()

parameters = {
    'penalty': ('l1', 'l2'),
    'C': (0.01, 0.1, 1, 10)
}
```

and it works well.

With that intuition I modified the pipeline to be:

```
pipeline = Pipeline([
    ('vect', TfidfVectorizer(stop_words='english')),
    ('clf', LogisticRegression())
])
```

Note that there is a `()` after `LogisticRegression`.
This time it works.

Comment: The `()` means you're _calling_ it. Calling a class constructs an instance of the class. Which is exactly what you have to do, as I explained in my answer.

Comment: @abarnert Thank you! I get your idea.

Comment: I got similar problem with lda = discriminant_analysis.LinearDiscriminantAnalysis(). Forgot () after instantiation

Comment: If @abarnert gave you the correct solution, I think the appropriate thing to do would be selecting his answer as the solution-- not your own.

Comment: @abarnert's answer helped me too! Why not mark it as the answer to the original question, instead of this one?